# How to get postmeta data where given post_id is array?

Tags: wordpress

How would i get a certain post_meta data where only the post_id is given, and take note, my post_id is an array of ids? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Post meta data function structure is such:

```
<?php $meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single); ?>
```

So if your $post_id variable is array then you can use something like this:

```
 <?php $meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id[0], $key, $single); ?>
```